# Cannot Install gulp-sass

Tags: node.js, sass, gulp, gulp-sass

I'm trying to learn how to use gulp / sass / and all the other fun tools with Nodejs and I'm having an issue installing gulp-sass. The process I'm using to install everything is:

```
1.  Start Git Bash in the project folder
2.  npm init
3.  npm install gulp -g
4.  npm install gulp --save-dev
5.  npm install gulp-sass <- this is where I get errors
```

Once I get to step five, I get the following error:

```
$ npm install gulp-sass
npm WARN package.json project@1.0.0 No repository field.
npm WARN package.json project@1.0.0 No README data
-
> node-sass@3.2.0 install     \\primary\home\mendsley\profile\Desktop\project\node_modules\gulp-  sass\node_modules\node-sass
> node scripts/install.js

'\\primary\home\mendsley\profile\Desktop\project\node_modules\gulp-   sass\node_modules\node-sass'
CMD.EXE was started with the above path as the current directory.
UNC paths are not supported.  Defaulting to Windows directory.
module.js:338
throw err;
      ^
Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Windows\scripts\install.js'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:336:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:278:25)
at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:501:10)
at startup (node.js:129:16)
at node.js:814:3
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! argv "c:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe"     "c:\\Users\\mendsley\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js"     "install" "gulp-sass"
npm ERR! node v0.12.1
npm ERR! npm  v2.13.1
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! node-sass@3.2.0 install: `node scripts/install.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the node-sass@3.2.0 install script 'node scripts/install.js'.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the node-sass package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node scripts/install.js
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls node-sass
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     \\primary\home\mendsley\profile\Desktop\project\npm-debug.log
```

I'm trying this on my work computer, so I'm not sure if that matters. The system admin says there should not be any issue and other people have no issue with same package...and talking to them, they offer no help. I tried everything on my personal laptop and `gulp-sass` installs just fine, so it is something with my work pc.

My initial thought is it's a path issue, but then why do other packages install okay?

I did uninstall/reinstall Nodejs, but that didn't help.

Does anyone have an idea?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Ah, okay...didn't think about that.

Comment: [tag:off-topic] mike your picture terrifies me.

Comment: Could you place your prompt in *C:/users/mendsley/profile/Desktop/project/* and try the `npm install gulp-sass` again ?

Comment: I added the code and removed that image

Comment: @ Michael P. - when I use the following path `/c/Users/mendsley/Desktop` I don't see my project folder. I did notice that my path in the Git Bash window shows `\\primary`, but for some reason I cannot get to that.

Comment: Ah. By the way, is `/c/Users/mendsley/Desktop` and `/c/Users/mendsley/profile/Desktop` pointing to the same folder?

Comment: When I `cd` into /c/users/mendsley/ and do an `ls` I don't see a profile folder, there are other use folders, but no profile.

Comment: Your project folder is probably on a network share

Comment: I'm thinking you're right. I'll talk with the system admin again and see if he offers any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your first guess was good as it is a matter of path name. From the error message :

> UNC paths are not supported.  Defaulting to Windows directory.

Npm needed to access `\\primary\home\mendsley\...\node_modules\node-sass` so as to execute the gulp-sass installation script. But this path is a *UNC path* (Uniform Naming Convention) and therefore is not supported.

As a consequence, the npm command defaulted to *C:/Windows* instead and tries to execute the installation script of gulp-sass (install.js) but this script is, as you might guess, not present in this directory.

Comment: Is there a way I can get around this issue? Can I tell npm to use a specific path?

Comment: In Windows you can map a drive letter to a network path. You could try that, although I admit I'm not sure that will make progress.

Comment: So after talking with another system admin guy, the problem WAS the path. I was creating a folder on my desktop which is on a network and not actually on my machine. So I went into `C: > Users > MYNAME` and created my project folder that way. Once I did that, everything installed just fine. I'm sure folks will not like this, but you turned me onto the the resolution by bringing up the network share so I'm giving you the credit. Thank you :)

Comment: You're welcome. For the record, you could also try to map a drive letter, for example `Z:`, to the path `\\primary\home` and execute the install from `Z:\mendsley\profile\Desktop\project`. That might do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

It could be a **dependency hell** problem with an older NodeJS or NPM version, too. `gulp-sass` depends on `node-sass`, which in turn depends on other packages, and they also depend on the right NodeJS and NPM version. For version `0.7.3` the full dependencies look like this:

`├─┬ gulp-sass@0.7.3
│ ├── map-stream@0.1.0
│ └─┬ node-sass@0.9.6
│   ├─┬ chalk@0.5.1
│   │ ├── ansi-styles@1.1.0
│   │ ├── escape-string-regexp@1.0.3
│   │ ├─┬ has-ansi@0.1.0
│   │ │ └── ansi-regex@0.2.1
│   │ ├─┬ strip-ansi@0.3.0
│   │ │ └── ansi-regex@0.2.1
│   │ └── supports-color@0.2.0
│   ├── get-stdin@3.0.2
│   ├─┬ mkdirp@0.5.1
│   │ └── minimist@0.0.8
│   ├─┬ mocha@1.21.5
│   │ ├── commander@2.3.0
│   │ ├─┬ debug@2.0.0
│   │ │ └── ms@0.6.2
│   │ ├── diff@1.0.8
│   │ ├── escape-string-regexp@1.0.2
│   │ ├─┬ glob@3.2.3
│   │ │ ├── graceful-fs@2.0.3
│   │ │ ├── inherits@2.0.1
│   │ │ └─┬ minimatch@0.2.14
│   │ │   ├── lru-cache@2.7.3
│   │ │   └── sigmund@1.0.1
│   │ ├── growl@1.8.1
│   │ ├─┬ jade@0.26.3
│   │ │ ├── commander@0.6.1
│   │ │ └── mkdirp@0.3.0
│   │ └─┬ mkdirp@0.5.0
│   │   └── minimist@0.0.8
│   ├── nan@1.3.0
│   ├── node-sass-middleware@0.3.1
│   ├── node-watch@0.3.5
│   ├── object-assign@1.0.0
│   ├─┬ sinon@1.10.3
│   │ ├─┬ formatio@1.0.2
│   │ │ └── samsam@1.1.3
│   │ └─┬ util@0.10.3
│   │   └── inherits@2.0.1
│   └── yargs@1.3.3`

I had trouble to install version 0.7.3 of `gulp-sass` with the latest versions of NodeJS `5.2.0` and NPM `3.5.2`. This older version of `gulp-sass` worked only with the older version of NodeJS `0.12.9` and NPM `2.14.9`, see also https://github.com/sass/node-sass/issues/1166

Answer (score 1):

Look at this:

> "CMD.EXE was started with the above path as the current directory.
>   UNC paths are not supported.  Defaulting to Windows directory."

You can use the `pushd` command. As example for --global Installation for a domain user on network share:

`pushd \\server\yourpath\user\AppData\Roaming\npm`

hint: you could figure out the right path for global npm installations by using `%appdata%\npm` in your Explorer, the cmd answers:

`Z:\user\AppData\Roaming\npm>`

now you can type "npm install node-sass" (or gulp-sass or whatever)

`Z:\user\AppData\Roaming\npm>npm install node-sass`

without --global or -g, in this path you are "global"

if finished, then `popd` to disconnect the `Z:`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I fixed it with simple step.

The real problem is with autorun to set the path of your command prompt. It is related to your registry.
i just deleted the autorun file in registry for command processor and it started working normally.

Hop in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41306846/installing-gulp-sass-throwing-error/41310878#41310878)