# Installing gulp-sass throwing error

Tags: node.js, gulp, gulp-sass

This question seems to be repeated of [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31573847/cannot-install-gulp-sass) but I cannot figure out how to map a drive letter or share network. I am really sorry for repeating but I need help.

I have a command prompt with default directory pointing to my www folder of wamp server.

```
D:\wamp\www\
```

I have install other gulp plugin such as gulp-minify. It works fine without any error. But when I try to install gulp-sass it throws error

[image: screenshot of error]

It happens to me most of the time like, I have been trying to install plugin such as optipng. It shows same error. Seems like it is searching for a "script" folder inside www which is not there. But the script folder is inside the c drive where the nodejs folder exist. Below is the exact path.

> C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\scripts

I don't understand why it is searching in my working directory ?

> D:\wamp\www\scripts\install.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only problem was with the autorun to set the path of command prompt. Few years back I had set the path of my command prompt to `D:\wamp\www\` from registry `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor`

You can access the registry by typing "regedit" in run dialog box (window + r)

i just deleted the autorun file and it started working normally.

[Credit link](https://github.com/sass/node-sass/issues/1012#issuecomment-115715502)